# How to handle out of bound exception inside Json object?

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, model-view-controller, datatable

I have a function that is returning a Json object as follows:

```
return Json(
                db.Select(c => new GridViewModel()
                {

                    Number = c.Rows[0][0].ToString(),
                    DocId = c.Rows[0][1].ToString(),
                    PartyName = c.Rows[0][2].ToString(),
                    FilingType = c.Rows[0][3].ToString(),
                    FilingDate = c.Rows[0][4].ToString(),

                }

            ).ToDataSourceResult(request));
```

db is a DataTable object, currently I just have one row so I am using index=0. I keep getting error massage in vs saying "An exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code" 
Is there a way how to add try catch inside a Json object?
Thanks

Comment: Why not break this up into multiple statements instead of one? That would allow you to determine exactly where the issue is coming from.

Comment: 1) What `Select` method are you using?   I don't see a [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx) overload on [`DataTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) that takes a `Func<T, TResult>`.  2) Similarly, what is `c` here?  A [`DataRow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135374.aspx)?

Comment: Yes c is DataRow. 0,1,2,3,4 are column index in the row. c is lambda expression I am using to bind the gridview to the data I am getting from the DataTable.

Comment: `c` cannot be a `DataRow` because [`DataRow` does not have a `Rows` property.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx).  I *suspect* that `c` is actually a `DataTable` and `db` is some container.  If that's true, in order for us to reliably help you, please edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataTable doesn't have `.Select(Func<...>)` method.

it has `DataTable.Select(string filterExpression)`, so it is very similar what you have in SQL e.g.

```
Select * from MyTable WHERE Column1 = 'something'
```

for DataTable it will be

```
var myFilteredRows = myDataTable.Select("Column1 = 'something'")
```

Please visit [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info.

According to your code I assume you want to use LINQ Enumerable.Select on non-enumerable object. Which is impossible :)

So, if you have DataSet then you can do this

```
DataSet myDataSet = init from database
```

then

```
dataSet.Tables.Cast<System.Data.DataTable>().Select(table => new YourObject
{
   init your object here, to get rows do this
   MyRows = table.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().Select(row => MyRowObject
   {
      init row object here
   })
});
```

If you have only one DataTable (not DataSet)
then

```
table.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().Select(row => GridViewModel
{
    Number = row[0].ToString(),
    DocId = row[1].ToString(),
    PartyName = row[2].ToString(),
    FilingType = row[3].ToString(),
    FilingDate = row[4].ToString(),           
});
```

Also I highly recommend to use column names and not indexes to avoid confusion in the future.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! that was very helpful. Yes I was actually trying to use Select on non-enumerable object.